# "Vi" in lieu of "ci" and "ovunque"

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

I just read the following short ***[Sputnik article](https://it.sputniknews.com/scienza-e-tech/202101059974593-identificati-i-prodotti-che-accorciano-la-vita/)*** and I am left wondering:

1. Why does it say *rinunciarvi* instead of *rinunciarci* as far as *il gelato* is concerned?
2. Is it normal to have a phrase like *gli esperti consigliano di acquistare carne ovunque sia possibile verificarne la qualità*?

I'd have added a conjunction between *carne* and *ovunque*.

Comment: I am confused. Why would you add a conjunction there? _Ovunque_ works more or less like “wherever” (...to buy meat wherever it's possible so and so).

Comment: These seem two unrelated questions - stackexchange works better if you ask them separately. Also I agree with DaG that it would be easier if you explained better what kind of construction would feel more natural to you in the second question.

Answer (score 7):

#### 1. "-vi" instead of "-ci"

You can do it whenever you want; they are exactly the same, it is just an issue of what sounds better to you (I tend to prefer "-vi" but "-ci" is more common). For example "*rinunciarci*" already has the sound "cia" so "*rinunciarvi*" might sound better; conversely "*viverci*" sounds better than "*vivervi*" in almost all cases (unless you explicitly want to repeat the "v" sound for poetic/musical reasons).

#### 2. "*Gli esperti consigliano di acquistare carne ovunque sia possibile verificarne la qualità.*"

If you add a conjunction, you change the meaning of the sentence.
As it is now, it means that you should buy meat (only) where you can verify its quality, if you say "*Gli esperti consigliano di acquistare carne **e**, ovunque sia possibile, verificarne la qualità.*" it means you should buy meat and, where it is possible, verify its quality (but it is ok even if you buy it from a place where you cannot verify its quality).